# load site on to different server

Tags: database

I want to move my drupal site onto another server. I installed drupal using drush & copied the `sites/` directory to where its suppposed to go. I then copied the database and changed credentials in `settings.php` - all seemed to make perfectly sense to me up to this point, wen i now go to `update.php`, I get this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'u.uid' in 'on clause': SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid; Array ( [:sid] => abcdefg ) in _drupal_session_read() (line 102 of /home/quaaout/public_html/drupal-7.34/includes/session.inc).
```

I'm wondering what this means and how I get my site up on the new server? What is a `PDOException`?

**UPDATE 1**

@PatrickRyan What I did is, I backed up the db using my GoDaddy interface on the old server, downloaded it to my local machine and uploaded it to my new server, creating a db with the same name as on the old server -> I changed the settings in `settings.php` to connect to the newly added db and that's how i'm getting that error. Where's my procedure wrong? What alternatives should I try?

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, what I did exactly, I backed up my old db using the GoDaddy Mysql backup utility (old server) and it stored the whole db in a file in my ftp under `_db_backups`. I downloaded that file and uploaded it in my GoDaddy cPanel (new server) under MySQL- Backup - Restore a MySQL Database Backup. That's created a new db in my cPanel featuring the same name as on my old server. I setup user and password, assigned it this db, verified that I can login from the shell but when I go to my URL, I still get: an error that says

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'u.uid' in 'on clause': SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid; Array ( [:sid] => 9uLxQl2polstrF1s6iYenrU1oB9M_rf0fecWUaI_FIs ) in _drupal_session_read() (line 102 of /home/quaaout/public_html/drupal-7.34/includes/session.inc).
```

underneath the error it says:

> **Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.**
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'uid' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {sessions} (sid,
>   ssid, uid, cache, hostname, session, timestamp) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =>
>   9uLxQl2polstrF1s6iYenrU1oB9M_rf0fecWUaI_FIs [:db_insert_placeholder_1]
>   => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 174.6.222.12 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => [:db_insert_placeholder_6] =>
>   1426465727 ) in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of
>   /home/quaaout/public_html/drupal-7.34/includes/session.inc).

What am I doing wrong??? :o

Comment: That indicates that there is an issue with the database settings or database.  Double check that you have your db transferred properly and that your db settings are all correct.

Comment: @PatrickRyan please see **UPDATE 1** above, Thanks